# Does performance.now() start on navigationStart?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, resource-timing-api

What is the origin time for performance.now()? Is it navigationStart, requestStart or something else?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp#The_time_origin

Comment: ...which is linked from [`now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) (which also has an important note about high-res timestamps).

Answer (score 0):

[MDN say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now#Example):

> performance.timing.navigationStart + performance.now() will be
>   approximately equal to Date.now()

performance.now() = Date.now() - performance.timing.navigationStart

The `performance.now()` start *navigationStart* ms [**beyond** January 1, 1970](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)!